# Apply same color to same entity in for each loop in vb

Tags: vb.net

Below code applies random color to all components in assembly irrespective of same or different name for each component. An assembly may have same named components packed together. I just want to apply same color when `tempComp.DisplayName` is same. I don't know how to check names during loop running or storing names somehow and compare.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
        Dim i as integer = 0
    For Each tempComp As Assemblies.Component In myAsmInfo.AllComponents
        lw.WriteLine(tempComp.DisplayName & " | Color ID:" & i)
        ''' Select random color between 1 to 216
        i = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 216)) + 1

        Dim markId1 As NXOpen.Session.UndoMarkId = Nothing
        markId1 = theSession.SetUndoMark(NXOpen.Session.MarkVisibility.Visible, "Edit Object Display")

        Dim displayModification1 As NXOpen.DisplayModification = Nothing
        displayModification1 = theSession.DisplayManager.NewDisplayModification()

        displayModification1.ApplyToAllFaces = True

        displayModification1.ApplyToOwningParts = False
        'lw.WriteLine("Color Before " & i)
        displayModification1.NewColor = i

        Dim objects1(0) As NXOpen.DisplayableObject

        objects1(0) = tempComp
        displayModification1.Apply(objects1)

        Dim nErrs1 As Integer = Nothing
        nErrs1 = theSession.UpdateManager.DoUpdate(markId1)

       ' lw.WriteLine("Color After " & i)
        displayModification1.Dispose()            

    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you require storing `tempComp.DisplayName` and a numeric value along side that name, you need to use a `Dictionary (Of String, Integer)` to hold the values.

Before you start the `For` loop, add the line:

```
Dim coloursDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

And, inside the `For` loop, when deciding on the colour to be assigned use:

```
If coloursDictionary.ContainsKey(tempComp.DisplayName) Then
    i = coloursDictionary(tempComp.DisplayName)
Else
    i = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 216)) + 1
    coloursDictionary(tempComp.DisplayName) = i
End If
```